# How can we upload blackberry application in blackberry world?

Tags: blackberry

How can we upload blackberry application in blackberry world ?

and which file we should upload .cod of .jad or any other ?

Thanks

Comment: hey go and explore these links  [help1](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/how-to-upload-application-on-Blackberry-app-world/td-p/556171)and [help2](http://us.blackberry.com/developers/appworld/faq.jsp)

Comment: This is not a topic for stackoverflow

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is the expected process when a new application is submitted for inclusion in the BlackBerry App World.

1. From the vendor portal for BlackBerry App World, under Manage Application, the vendor submits an application.
2. After step 7 of the submission process is complete, the vendor receives an email message confirming the submission. The BlackBerry App World team is notified of the new application.
3. The application is sent for vetting to confirm the following:

   - The application installs on supported BlackBerry® smartphones.
   - The application runs without error on supported BlackBerry smartphones.
   - BlackBerry smartphone users can make and receive voice calls while the application is running.
   - BlackBerry smartphone users can use the **Switch Application** feature from within the application.
   - The application uninstalls on supported BlackBerry smartphones.
4. Once the vetting is complete, the application is reviewed for suitability in BlackBerry App World. The following items are reviewed:

   - Screen shots do not contain any BlackBerry smartphone images.
   - The description is verified for clarity and correct branding.
   - The application icon does not contain a BlackBerry smartphone image, and the icon is clear and accurate for the application.
   - The minimum BlackBerry® Device Software version is confirmed. For example, the minimum BlackBerry Device Software version is 4.7.0 for the BlackBerry® Storm™ 9500.
   - After the application has passed the vetting and suitability reviews, the application is approved for sale on BlackBerry App World1.
   - Once the vendor receives a notification email message, the vendor can log in to the vendor portal for BlackBerry App World, and then click **Post for Sale** beside the application.

The following is the expected process when a new release is submitted for inclusion in BlackBerry App World.

1. The Vendor adds a new release to the Release tab within a target application in the Vendor Portal for BlackBerry App World.
2. Upon saving the changes of the new release, the BlackBerry App World Manager is notified of a new release for review.
3. The release is sent for vetting to confirm the following:

   - The release installs on supported BlackBerry smartphones.
   - The release runs without error on supported BlackBerry smartphones.
   - BlackBerry smartphone users can make and receive voice calls while the application is running.
   - BlackBerry smartphone users can use the **Switch Application** feature from within the application.
   - The application uninstalls on supported BlackBerry smartphones.
4. Once the application has passed the vetting review, the application is approved for inclusion in BlackBerry App World.
   With new releases, the vendor does not need to perform any tasks once the approval is sent. The new release is automatically available on BlackBerry App World within the corresponding cache time2.
5. Application submissions take 8-10 business days from submission to approval.
6. See [here](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/1573156/What_Is_-_The_BlackBerry_App_World_storefront_cache.html?nodeid=1577562&vernum=0) for more information on caching with BlackBerry App World.

Comment: i can see only 5 step at there

Comment: and i never asked for upload or browse .Jad file during prossess

Comment: Hi @BBdev, question about the Switch Application. What if I customize my Menu and Switch Application is not included on MenuItems, does it mean that my app won't be approve by blackberry? or what you meant of Switch Application was, the submitted application could be minimize? Thanks!